# NSPredicate to retrieve all parents with specific children ? (IOS)

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

Say I have the following Core Data structure in IOS:

```
Parent1
    Child1.1: Text='A', Number=1
    Child1.2: Text='B', Number=1
Parent2
    Child2.1: Text='B', Number=1
    Child2.2: Text='A', Number=2
Parent3
    Child3.1: Text='B', Number=2
    Child3.2: Text='A', Number=1
```

I want to retrive all parents that have a child with Text='A' and Number=1 (Parent1 and Parent3 in the above example).

Basically what I need is a predicate on the Parent entity that looks like:

```
ANY (child.Text = 'A' AND child.Number = 1)
```

But this doesn't work - it seems that I cannot have parentheses following an ANY keyword.

The following isn't good either (even though it's valid):

```
ANY child.Text = 'A' AND ANY child.Number = 1
```

because it returns Parent2 as well.

Is there a way to do this in a predicate, or do I have to do it programmatically (e.g. retrieve just the children without using an ANY keyword and construct an array of parents from the back relationships)?

Answer (score 0):

In a predicate you have to use == for equality - does it work then?

You can also have a look at the NSCompoundPredicate for combining predicate parts with AND and OR, like

```
NSMutableArray* predicatesToCombine = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[predicatesToCombine addObject:@"child.Text == 'A'"];
[predicatesToCombine addObject:@"child.Number == 1"];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicatesToCombine];

...

[predicatesToCombine release];
```

Comment: NSPredicate converts = to ==, both are the same. Also, I'm already using NSCompoundPredicate (the example I gave was simplified) and it has nothing to do with the problem - it only combines simple predicates with AND or OR or precedes a simple predicate with NOT. My issue is the ANY keyword followed by parentheses, not what's inside the parentheses.

Comment: @AmiramStark, You will get better answers by showing your actual code rather than "simplified examples" otherwise people will waste time telling you to try things you may already be trying.

Comment: jrturon, I see no point in showing tens of lines of complex code when there's no difference whatsoever between the actual code and a simplified one. Double equal signs are irrelevant according to the official NSPredicate format string syntax and compound predicates do nothing regarding the ANY keyword. A simplified code helps focus on the actual problem and I believe it's a much better way.